# getting google images through python. JSON object must be str issue

Tags: python, json, urllib

I am trying to get some google images through python, However when I try to read the json response from the server i am getting an error telling me that the object must be str instead of bytes.
As a matter of fact, I tried to solve the issue by converting the respond of the server to str by decoding it ( utf-8). I am getting another error telling me  "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"
**Here is what I have done**
1. I search for BLACK SHIRTS on google and clicked on image rubric. I copied the URL.
2. I create headers where I inform that the user-agent is chrome (in order not to get blocked when sending the request to the server )
3. I create a request
4. I read the request
5. when i try to load it I got the issue mentioned above. So i tried to decode the output of step 4 ( by adding this    **.decode('utf-8')** .

**Here is the code that I used**

```
import os
import urllib.request as ulib
import urllib.parse
import json


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'} 
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=BLACK+SHIRTS&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS2NPpxPbbAhWlMewKHSpiC9IQ_AUICygC&biw=1600&bih=794' ## this is the url when i searched
request = ulib.Request(url, None, headers)
json_string = ulib.urlopen(request).read()
json_string=json_string.decode('utf-8')
page = json.loads(json_string)
```

PS: remove ***.decode('utf-8')*** from the 4th step ( that matchs the line before last )

Comment: have you tried using requests? may make this easier

Comment: This url returns html page in response instead of json-parsable object. I guess that's why you can't parse it even after converting to string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the HTML response with a package like Beautiful Soup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/?